# R finding patterns in numbers/layouts

Tags: r, pattern-recognition

*Consider a database with the following structure*:

```
<Age> <Gender> <Field1> <Field2> <Field3> <Field4> <Field#>
```

**Where for each row, some fields might be zero, others will not, representing the amount of times the individual used such field - multiple fields may be used for each row.**

For instance, consider the DB as being:

```
10 M 10 0 5 0 1
5  M  7 1 6 0 2
10 M  6 1 4 1 0
....
```

So one could say that the pattern for individuals of age 10 and male gender, would be the first and third fields as being the most representative.

I'm not sure if my explanation is making sense. Is this achievable? Is there any algorithm/R package for such problems?

Comment: Wouldn't `Field1` and `Field3` be the most used ones?

Comment: Yes it would, I misswrote it haha thanks

Answer (score 0):

What comes to mind is to subset.  If I'm understanding your question correctly.
Look up subsetting, I'm not positive my code is correct...

> df[which(df$Age=10 & df$Gender=M),]

Comment: I appreciate the help @Valerie S, but that is not the point. Do imagine you'd subset the data according to the age tag 10 and male gender, you'd end up with - in the provided exemple - two rows. Now for those two rows, what I'm trying to achieve, is to detect the pattern on the existing fields "Field*", by frequency I suppose.